# What was the value of trillion during Mahabharata time as population of Yadavas is mentioned as 30 trillion+ in SB 10.90.42?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavata-purana, chandravansh, yadavas, numbers

[SB 10.90.42](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/90/42)

> saṅkhyānaṁ yādavānāṁ kaḥ
>
> kariṣyati mahātmanām
>
> yatrāyutānām ayuta-
>
> lakṣeṇāste sa āhukaḥ
>
> Who can count all the great Yādavas, when among them King Ugrasena alone was accompanied by an entourage of **thirty trillion** attendants?

**30 trillion+** is a very big number, however, the population of Yadavs seems to be quite large at that time:

> The members of the Yadu dynasty are virtually innumerable; indeed, just to educate their children the Yadus employed 38,800,000 teachers. - [SB 10.90](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/90)
>
> The Yadu dynasty produced innumerable great men of famous deeds. Even in tens of thousands of years, O King, one could never count them all. - [SB 10.90](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/90)

Comment: it cannot be trillion as understood today.  The whole earth's area is around 200 million square miles, 30.10^12 divided by 2.10^8 is an impossible population density even if yadavas lived all over the world.

Comment: @SK yes..thats what my doubt is..

Comment: Most of the Hindu scriptures are written in poems so makes sense they use poetic devices like Exaggeration/hyperbole http://literary-devices.com/content/hyperbole

Comment: Here's another absurd figure from the [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02064.htm): "Yudhishthira said,--O son of Suvala, I know that I have untold wealth. But why is it, O Sakuni, that thou askest me of my wealth? Let **tens of thousands and millions and millions and tens of millions and hundreds of millions and tens of billions and hundreds of billions and trillions and tens of trillions and hundreds of trillions and tens of quadrillions and hundreds of quadrillions** and even more wealth be staked by thee. I have as much. With that wealth, O king, I will play with thee."

Comment: @sv. There were much smallest units too..what if wealth unit is too too small here?

Comment: @YDS Yes, if you are talking about grains of sand on a beach, stars in a galaxy or atoms in those stars. But in reality nobody uses such small units. People used gold/silver/copper/bronze coins or promissory notes they can see and hold in their hands.

Comment: Is it written that full Yadava's population lived all together, at same time (all full race) incarnated? And all living on Bhumi Loka?

Comment: @sv. - That is excellent find , I think you should post answer based on your comment.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar @ sv. The shloka says अयुतं परयुतं चैव खर्वं पद्मं तथार्बुदम, शङ्खं चैव निखर्वं च समुद्रं चात्र पण्यताम, एतन मम धनं राजंस तेन दीव्याम्य अहं तवया.. it clearly mention all Indian big numbers, only it's unit is unclear here...this seems another Qn to me and not an answer... :)

Comment: @YDS - Ok . I think i saw value of  gems equated with grains and other items. But those were small numbers compared to this .

Comment: @sv. Hahaha. Millions and thousand of trillions and millions of..... Maybe these were just metaphors .

Answer (score 2):

Refer the numbering system [here](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Indian_numbering_system.html) comparing Sanskrit and western numbering:

> शङ्कु (śaṅku)     1,00,000 koṭi   1012    10,00,00,00,00,000  One trillion

Perhaps what is stated above in your question is an exaggerated figure, what we normally term as "Atishyokti".

It's just like when we ask some one how many people came to watch the match, so if a person does not have an idea about the exact figures then perhaps he will reply (rather than not replying) that there were thousands and thousands of people, but that doesn't mean 1000 times 1000 or 10,00,000 .. as has been interpreted above:

> yatrāyutānām ayuta-
>
> lakṣeṇāste sa āhukaḥ

Just quoting some population figures as stated [here](http://veda.wikidot.com/hindu-timeline) before/after Vedic age:

> Proto-Vedic Period - World population 4 million; India is 100,000.
>   -10,000
>
> -4000: India's population is 1 million.
>
> 2600: Harappa and Mohenjo-daro have populations of 100,000.
>
> Late Vedic Period
>
> 2000: World population: 27 million. India: 5 million

Comment: i think..that's how numbers are written...who writes exact numbers for big figures..for an instance most of the time people write 1.76 lakh crore for 2G scam.. and if someone writes it to Sanskrit, i believe it will be similar to the Qn's verse..