# Inconsistency in the number of people died in Kurukshetra war

Tags: mahabharata, kurukshetra

From [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16078/661) answer, we can get the following information:

Total number of persons participated in war is almost 4,723,920.

Total number of persons died in war is 1,660,020,000.

Both figures have a high variation. Is there any reason behind this inconsistency?

Sanskrit Verses:

> [Adi Parva 2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01002.htm) : For Akshauhini details
>
> ```
> 15 [स]
>  एकॊ रथॊ जगश चैकॊ नराः पञ्च पदातयः
>
>  तरयश च तुरगास तज्ज्ञैः पत्तिर इत्य अभिधीयते
>
> 16 पत्तिं तु तरिगुणाम एताम आहुः सेनामुखं बुधाः
>
>  तरीणि सेनामुखान्य एकॊ गुल्म इत्य अभिधीयते
>
> 17 तरयॊ गुल्मा गणॊ नाम वाहिनी तु गणास तरयः
>
>  समृतास तिस्रस तु वाहिन्यः पृतनेति विचक्षणैः
>
> 18 चमूस तु पृतनास तिस्रस तिस्रश चम्वस तव अनीकिनी
>
>  अनीकिनीं दशगुणां पराहुर अक्षौहिणीं बुधाः
>
>  19 अक्षौहिण्याः परसंख्यानं रथानां दविजसत्तमाः
>
>  संख्या गणित तत्त्वज्ञैः सहस्राण्य एकविंशतिः
>
> 20 शतान्य उपरि चैवाष्टौ तथा भूयश च सप्ततिः
>
>  गजानां तु परीमाणम एतद एवात्र निर्दिशेत
>
>  21 जञेयं शतसहस्रं तु सहस्राणि तथा नव
>
>  नराणाम अपि पञ्चाशच छतानि तरीणि चानघाः
>
>  22 पञ्च षष्टिसहस्राणि तथाश्वानां शतानि च
>
>  दशॊत्तराणि षट पराहुर यथावद इह संख्यया
>
>  23 एताम अक्षौहिणीं पराहुः संख्या तत्त्वविदॊ जनाः
>
>  यां वः कथितवान अस्मि विस्तरेण दविजॊत्तमाः
> ```
>
> [Udyoga Parva 152](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs05152.htm) : For Pandava Army details
>
> ```
>  22 वाहिनी पृतना सेना धवजिनी सादिनी चमूः
>
> अक्षौहिणीति पर्यायैर निरुक्ताथ वरूथिनी
>
> एवं वयूढान्य अनीकानि कौरवेयेण धीमता
>
> 23 अक्षौहिण्यॊ दशैका च संख्याताः सप्त चैव ह
>
> अक्षौहिण्यस तु सप्तैव पाण्डवानाम अभूद बलम
>
> अक्षौहिण्यॊ दशैका च कौरवाणाम अभूद बलम
> ```
>
> [Bhishma Parva 19](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs06019.htm) : For Kaurava army details
>
> ```
> 1 [धृ]
>   अक्षौहिण्यॊ दशैकां च वयूढां दृष्ट्वा युधिष्ठिरः
>
>   कथम अल्पेन सैन्येन परत्यव्यूहत पाण्डवः
>
>   2 यॊ वेद मानुषं वयूहं दैवं गान्धर्वम आसुरम
>
>   कथं भीष्मं स कौन्तेयः परत्यव्यूहत पाण्डवः
> ```
>
> [Stri Parva 26](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs11026.htm) : For count of died and alive people
>
> ```
>  9 [य]
>   दशायुतानाम अयुतं सहस्राणि च विंशतिः
>
>   कॊट्यः षष्टिश च षट चैव ये ऽसमिन राजमृधे हताः
>
>   10 अलक्ष्याणां तु वीराणां सहस्राणि चतुर्दश
>
>  दश चान्यानि राजेन्द्र शतं षष्टिश च पञ्च च
> ```

Comment: can't go by english translations when you want to research original facts.. can you post the sanskrit verses ?

Comment: @ram I updated as per my trial and error knowledge on Sanskrit. Please  have a look.

Comment: may be animals also got added...and it seems translation from sanskrit numbers to todays math have some issues...may be that era's million/billion is not same as of today's... similar Q https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24708/12304

Comment: @YDS I want to learn Sanskrit slowly, can you suggest me a good site or a way to learn it properly?

Comment: So 1.6 billion people died in the Kurukshetra war?! Color me skeptical