# What scriptures describe the world’s population in earlier Yugas?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, yuga, time

[This chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/90) of the Srimad Bhagavatam describes the extremely large number of Yadavas who lived during the time of Krishna:

> I have heard from authoritative sources that the Yadu family employed 38,800,000 teachers just to educate their children. Who can count all the great Yādavas, when among them King Ugrasena alone was accompanied by an entourage of thirty trillion attendants?

But of course there were more humans at the time than just Yadavas.  So my question is, what the total number of humans in the world at the time of Krishna?

Or if that isn’t described in Hindu scripture, are there any scriptures that speak about the total number of humans in the world in some other time in a previous Yuga?

Note that I don’t want scientific speculation, I just want to know what Hindu scripture says on the subject.

Comment: Thirty trillion attendants!!! Is that even feasible on earth? I think we should reinterpret it to mean "a large number of attendants".

Comment: Related [What was the value of trillion during Mahabharata time as population of Yadavas is mentioned as 30 trillion+ in SB 10.90.42?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24708/16823)

Comment: Are you asking specifically during time of Krishna or in earlier yugas? Because in body your question has related to Krishna and in title yugas

Comment: I didnt mark as duplicate because the question itself is not clear!